# When does suspension points in haskell should work with an extra "space"?

Tags: parsing, haskell, space

When defining lists, we use suspension points without extra spaces like this:

```
Prelude> [3..5]
[3,4,5]
Prelude> [3 .. 5]
[3,4,5]
```

But used with enumerations seems extra spaces are required:

```
Prelude> [LT..GT]

<interactive>:2:2: Not in scope: ‘LT..’

<interactive>:2:2:
    A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (LT.. GT)
Prelude> [LT .. GT]
[LT,EQ,GT]
```

So question is: is it a syntax rule in Haskell? Or related to implementations?

Comment: The problem is that parsers work by matching the longest portion of text possible. For the same reason in (e.g.) python `1.bit_length()` yields an error because it is parsed as `1.` `bit_length` and the syntax doesn't allow to juxtapose a float to a name, while writing `1 .bit_length()` the parser recognizes the `1` as an integer cal the `.bit_length()` as a call to the method `bit_length`.  In your case you just need a space after `LT`: `[LT ..GT] == [LT,EQ;GT]`.

Answer (score 7):

`LT` is a valid module name, and therefore you refer to the function `(.)` in that module name (or alias), not the syntactic sugar for enumerations. Since you didn't import `LT` (the module, not the data constructor), all of it's hypothetical functions are out of scope.

Here's a bogus example that does not lead to an out of scope error:

```
Prelude> import Prelude hiding (LT)
Prelude> import qualified Prelude as LT
Prelude LT> [LT..GT]

<interactive>:3:2:
    A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (LT.. GT)
```

Even with the parentheses it wouldn't type check. The section error can also be achieved with a single list:

```
Prelude> [+ 1]
<interactive>:1:2:
    A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (+ 1)

Prelude> :t [(+ 1)]
[(+ 1)] :: Num a => [a -> a]
```

**TL;DR:** Unless you want to specify something from another module, make sure have some space between `.` and a valid module name.

Comment: Isn't the `LT..` thing going to be changed in future haskell versions (i.e. requiring to use `LT.(.)`)? I'm pretty sure I've heard that.